# C# & Win32 notify when separate window is closing / closed

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, events

Is there a way to attach an event to a foreign / separate window from an .NET process that when the foreign window is closed or is about to close my application can be notified?

I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229658.aspx

But that seems to only be for the .NET compact framework. I am looking for something using the .NET 2.0 framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx) that looks at using global hooks to receive windows messages from other applications.

Can you [wait for the process to exit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369)?

Or are you stuck needing to poll and check that you can still [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) the window?

Answer (score 0):

Look into SetWindowsHookEx with the WH_CBT parameter. There will be a HCBT_DESTROYWND entry.