# Close another process when application is closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winform application that during its work opens another Winform process. The other process has UI of its own.
When I close the parent application, I want the other application to be closed automatically.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169483/c-win32-notify-when-separate-window-is-closing-closed

Comment: That refers to a similar, but opposite, task (shutting down the current app when another window closes). The CodeProject article linked there should however be of some use.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Process.Process` there is the `CloseMainWindow` method. If you keep a reference to the object you can use it later.

Here's the relevant page in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(VS.71).aspx)

and the relevant code:

```
// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
// Free resources associated with process.
myProcess.Close();
```

Comment: I can't see the reason to downvote this one; it's a perfectly workable solution (even though I would add a call to CloseMainWindow before calling the Close method).

Comment: Down-voted for the same reason as Shoban's answer. This is not the right way to close a process.

Comment: OK so I got the wrong method to start with, but really reading the MSDN page gave the correct one - which I'm sure the OP is capable of doing

Comment: Down-vote removed. CloseMainWindow is actually the way to go. :)

Comment: Thanks - I should have double checked the help page myself ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are several different options. I would suggest that you have your application keep track of the processes that it starts:

```
private Stack<Process> _startedProcesses = new Stack<Process>();
private void StartChildProcess(string fileName)
{
    Process newProcess = new Process();
    newProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName); ;
    newProcess.Start();    
    _startedProcesses.Push(newProcess);
}
```

When the application closes, you can call a method that will close all started child processes that are still running. You can use this either with the Kill method or by calling the CloseMainWindow and Close methods. CloseMainWindow/Close will perform a more graceful close (if you start Notepad and there are unsaved changes, Kill will lose them, CloseMainWindow/Close will make notepad ask if you want to save):

```
private void CloseStartedProcesses()
{
    while (_startedProcesses.Count > 0)
    {
        Process process = _startedProcesses.Pop();
        if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
        {
            process.CloseMainWindow();
            process.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most graceful way to do this is probably to send a window message to the main from of the other process. You can get the handle of this main form simply using the `Process.MainWindow.Handle` property (I assume you are using the `Process` class, and then just use the `PostMessage` Win API call to send a message with a custom ID to the main window of this "child" process. Then, the message loop of the other process can easily detect this message (by overriding the `WndProc` method) and perform a proper shutdown accordingly. An alternative would be to send the standard `WM_CLOSE` method, which would mean you would just have to unload the application from the handler of the `Form.Closed` event, but may perhaps allow you less control (over whether to cancel the shutdown in certain situations).